# akka-http Multipart.FormData handler rejecting request due to "Content-Type"

Tags: scala, file-upload, akka, multipartform-data, akka-http

Please bear with me... I am new to FP, Scala and Akka/Akka-Http...

I am trying to handle multi-part file upload requests in a general and flexible manner.

I started by using the FileUploadDirectives.fileUpload to handle uploaded files, but I am not satisfied with it due to it requiring the "fieldName" be known in advance, and further, it cannot support multiple files which use the same form fieldName (only the first will be seen).

This route behaves as expected...

```
$ curl -i -X POST -F "file=@zipped_sums.zip" http://localhost:8012/upload

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
Server: REST API
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 04:13:10 GMT

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: REST API
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 04:13:10 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 157

Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: ZIP file type not supported for zipped_sums.zip - Request to http://localhost:8012/upload could not be handled normally%
```

So, I found a code sample that appears to be able to iterate thru all form parts, allowing me to handle them 1 at a time.  I implemented this route and it compiles and starts up without errors.  However, the curl request (which worked fine with the fileUpload-based route) will get rejected with:

```
$ curl -i -X POST -F "file=@zipped_sums.zip" http://localhost:8012/uploadmany

HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
Server: REST API
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 03:40:21 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 71

The request's Content-Type is not supported. Expected:
application/json%
```

The example code below are both from published examples, and the functions they are performing are not related to my end functional goals.  I am just trying to understand/implement a good pattern for handling incoming multi-part file uploads (with different names/types receiving different handling).

The working code (which properly complains about not supporting ZIP files) looks like this:

```
  path("upload") {
    post {
      extractRequestContext { ctx =>
        implicit val materializer = ctx.materializer
        implicit val ec = ctx.executionContext
        fileUpload("file") {
          case (metadata, byteSource) => {
            val content_type = metadata.contentType.mediaType.subType
            val fileName = metadata.fileName
            val fieldName = metadata.fieldName

            if (fileName.endsWith(".zip")) {
              throw new RuntimeException( s"ZIP file type not supported for $fileName")
            } else {
              val sumF: Future[Int] =
              // sum the numbers as they arrive so that we can
              // accept any size of file
                byteSource.via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), 1024))
                  .mapConcat(_.utf8String.split(",").toVector)
                  .map(_.toInt)
                  .runFold(0) { (acc, n) => acc + n }
              onSuccess(sumF) { sum => complete(s"Sum: $sum") }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } ~
```

and the code which rejects zip files as "Content-Type is not supported" is this...

```
  path("uploadmany") {
    post {
      println("In post")
      entity(as[Multipart.FormData]) { (formdata: Multipart.FormData) =>
        println("In entity")
        extractRequestContext { ctx =>
          implicit val materializer = ctx.materializer
          implicit val ec = ctx.executionContext

          val fileNamesFuture = formdata.parts.mapAsync(1) { p =>
            println(s"Got part. name: ${p.name} filename: ${p.filename}")

            println("Counting size...")
            @volatile var lastReport = System.currentTimeMillis()
            @volatile var lastSize = 0L

            def receiveChunk(counter: (Long, Long), chunk: ByteString): (Long, Long) = {
              val (oldSize, oldChunks) = counter
              val newSize = oldSize + chunk.size
              val newChunks = oldChunks + 1

              val now = System.currentTimeMillis()
              if (now > lastReport + 1000) {
                val lastedTotal = now - lastReport
                val bytesSinceLast = newSize - lastSize
                val speedMBPS = bytesSinceLast.toDouble / 1000000 /* bytes per MB */ / lastedTotal * 1000 /* millis per second */

                println(f"Already got $newChunks%7d chunks with total size $newSize%11d bytes avg chunksize ${newSize / newChunks}%7d bytes/chunk speed: $speedMBPS%6.2f MB/s")

                lastReport = now
                lastSize = newSize
              }
              (newSize, newChunks)
            }

            println(s"@ p.entity.dataBytes.runFold")
            p.entity.dataBytes.runFold((0L, 0L))(receiveChunk).map {
              case (size, numChunks) =>
                println(s"Size is $size")
                (p.name, p.filename, size)
            }
          }.runFold(Seq.empty[(String, Option[String], Long)])(_ :+ _).map(_.mkString(", "))

          complete {
            fileNamesFuture
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

A final detail... The "In post" line is printed, but the "In entity" line is not.

Can anyone explain to me why the 2nd example if being rejected as expecting application/json types, and how to remove this constraint?  And what is the key difference between these two fragments in the context of supported/required form data types?

I thank you for your feedback...  I am stumped.

Comment: Your code looks correct. Please check your code for JSON handling that you have defined in the project. Which is making that every request coming to the server is to be a type of JSON i.e you are facing this issue. This will help you

Comment: I appreciate the thought, but since (in the exact same process/build) another route (shown in the 1st example) has no problem receiving a ZIP (non-JSON) multi-part payload, it seems to me that it's not project-related.  Does this thinking make sense?

Comment: Do you able to handle the simple form data? if yes then there is the problem in the Multipart form data handling else check the JSON handler.

Comment: I tried handing form fields with:
            formFields('color, 'age.as[Int]) { (color,age) =>
              val msg = s"color=$color age=$age"
              println(msg)
              complete( msg )
            }
and got the same failed result:
'The request's Content-Type is not supported. Expected:
application/json'

So where do I find the JSON-handler in the project?  I don't see how JSON is coming into play here.

Comment: can you give me the code I will try to resolve the issue?

Comment: Dhirenda, you correctly identified the root cause.  The implementation that I am working within had the service deriving (several layers back) from a JSON package that provided automatic unmarshaling of JSON HTTP bodies into Scala Case Classes.  This was interfering with my attempts to unmarshal non-JSON multipart-files.  I found 2 solutions that worked.  1) Have the route in question bypass that inheritance path, or 2) supplement the entity() invocation with an override of the implicit unmarshaller with a 2-step chain....

Comment: From this....

entity(as[Multipart.FormData]) { (formdata: Multipart.FormData) =>

to this...

entity(as[Multipart.FormData](Unmarshaller.messageUnmarshallerFromEntityUnmarshaller(MultipartUnmarshallers.multipartFormDataUnmarshaller()))) { (formdata: Multipart.FormData) =>

Comment: Please upvote my comment.